# Swift 5: Display Data Retrieved in Closure to Table View

Tags: ios, swift, api, networking

I've successfully obtained some data from my API in a closure within a function. I need to display the data to the table on my storyboard.

I know the reason why it's not displaying is because the data is saved within the closure and I can't access it from the outside unless I have a completion handler. I've read a bunch of other questions here on Stack Overflow but I can't really understand it. I've tried reloading the table as well, but it just returns an error of 'Unexpectedly found nil'.

Claim Properties

```
class ClaimProperties {
    var id: Int
    var date: String
    var status: String

    init(id: Int, date: String, status: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.date = date
        self.status = status
    }
}
```

DashboardController

```
struct Claims: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let submission_date: String
    let status: String
    init(json: [String:Any]) {
        id = json["id"] as? Int ?? -1
        submission_date = json["submission_date"] as? String ?? ""
        status = json["status"] as? String ?? ""
    }
}

class DashboardController: UIViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var tempArray: [ClaimProperties] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    // getTokenFromAPI() gets called form AppDelegate.swift once the user logs in via Google API

    func getTokenFromAPI(usersAppToken:String) {
        guard let urlString = URL(string: "https://claim.ademo.work/claims/") else { return }
        var requestAPI = URLRequest(url: urlString)

        requestAPI.httpMethod = "GET"
        requestAPI.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        requestAPI.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        requestAPI.setValue("Bearer \(usersAppToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: requestAPI) {
            (data, response, error) in
            if let data = data {
                do {

                    let json = try JSONDecoder().decode([Claims].self, from: data)

                    for n in 0..<json.count {
                        self.tempArray.append(ClaimProperties(id: json[n].id, date: json[n].submission_date, status: json[n].status))
                    }

                    // This is the data I'm trying to display -> tempArray

                } catch let error {
                    print("Localized Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

extension DashboardController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tempArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ClaimCell", for: indexPath) as! AllMyClaimsTable
        cell.idField.text = String(tempArray[indexPath.section].id)
        cell.dateField.text = tempArray[indexPath.section].date
        cell.statusField.text = tempArray[indexPath.section].status
        return cell
    }
}
```

In summary, what I'm trying to do is just to display API data to my table view.

Comment: Maybe it should be indexPath.row instead of indexPath.section, from a cursory examination (inside your cellForRow implementation).

Comment: Now `section` is 0 so if `tempArray` has some values the implementation like `tempArray[indexPath.section]` must return value in first(0) index. But OP said `Unexpectedly found nil` error occurred.

Comment: I agree with you @emrcftci, but still for the data to show correctly the implementation in `cellForRow` should be corrected as well.

Comment: @Wattholm yes you are right, should be done with `tempArray[indexPath.row]` instead of `tempArray[indexPath.section]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## **Solution:**

After searching around and amending my code, below is the working solution:

Dashboard Controller

```
import UIKit

struct Claims: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let submission_date: String
    let status: String
    
    init(json: [String:Any]) {
        id = json["id"] as? Int ?? -1
        submission_date = json["submission_date"] as? String ?? ""
        status = json["status"] as? String ?? ""
    }
}

class DashboardController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var dashboardMyClaim: UITableView!
    var myClaimArray: [PropertyExistingClaim] = []
    var idToken = ""
    var email = ""
    var appToken = ""
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        idToken = AppDelegate.originalAppDelegate.userIdToken
        email = AppDelegate.originalAppDelegate.userEmail
        tableSettings()
        getAppToken()
    }
    
    func tableSettings() {
        dashboardMyClaim.delegate = self
        dashboardMyClaim.dataSource = self
    }
    
    // Get user's App Token from Google API

    func getAppToken() {
        guard let urlString = URL(string: "https://claim.ademo.work/sessions/") else { return }
        var requestAPI = URLRequest(url: urlString)

        let parameters: [String: Any] = ["email":email, "platform":"web", "id_token":idToken]
        requestAPI.httpMethod = "POST"
        requestAPI.setValue("Application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: []) else {return}
        requestAPI.httpBody = httpBody
        requestAPI.timeoutInterval = 20
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: requestAPI) { (data, response, error) in
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let jsonResult = try JSONDecoder().decode(SignIn.self, from: data)
                    self.getClaimFromAPI(usersAppToken: jsonResult.app_token)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    
    // Use the App Token to GET claims from the database / API

    func getClaimFromAPI(usersAppToken:String) {
        guard let urlString = URL(string: "https://claim.ademo.work/claims/") else { return }
        var requestAPI = URLRequest(url: urlString)

        requestAPI.httpMethod = "GET"
        requestAPI.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        requestAPI.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        requestAPI.setValue("Bearer \(usersAppToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: requestAPI) { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let json = try JSONDecoder().decode([Claims].self, from: data)

                    for n in 0..<json.count {
                        self!.myClaimArray.append(PropertyExistingClaim(id: json[n].id, date: json[n].submission_date, desc: "-", amount: "-", amountMyr: "-", currency: "-", status: json[n].status))
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self!.dashboardMyClaim.reloadData()
                    }
                    
                } catch let error {
                    print("Localized Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                }

            }
        }.resume()
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goToNewClaimDashboard" {
            let destinationVC = segue.destination as? NewClaimDashboardController
        }
    }
}

extension DashboardController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        myClaimArray.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = dashboardMyClaim.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DashboardMyClaim", for: indexPath) as! TableDashboardMyClaim
        cell.dateField.text = "Date: \(myClaimArray[indexPath.row].date)"
        cell.descriptionField.text = "Description: \(myClaimArray[indexPath.row].desc)"
        cell.amountMyrField.text = "RM \(myClaimArray[indexPath.row].amountMyr)"
        cell.idField.text = "#\(myClaimArray[indexPath.row].id)"
        cell.statusField.text = "\(myClaimArray[indexPath.row].status)"
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 120.0
    }
    
}
```

I think adding this has helped quite abit:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self!.dashboardMyClaim.reloadData()
}
```

Special thanks to all those that has helped me on this question. I really appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Move your `reload` line under to for loop

```swift
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: requestAPI) { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
    if let data = data {
        do {

            let json = try JSONDecoder().decode([Claims].self, from: data)

            for n in 0..<json.count {
                self?.tempArray.append(ClaimProperties(id: json[n].id, date: json[n].submission_date, status: json[n].status))
            }
            self?.tableView.reloadData()

        } catch let error {
            print("Localized Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}.resume()
```

You need to reload after the loop is over, after `tempArray` is completely filled.

Comment: self?.tableView.reloadData() gives an error of: "Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type 'DashboardController'" so I removed the question mark.

After that, I got an error of "Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: Please add `[weak self]` before `(data, response, error)`, please re-check my answer :) Can you tell me which line you face with the error? @ShaniceC.

Comment: Oops! Sorry, missed that part. I've tried, still shows the same error. Screenshot here for your reference: https://flic.kr/p/2iAq97Y

Comment: I think your `tableView` is `nil` please check your `tableView`'s outlet connection.

Comment: Can you tell me which property is `nil`? `self` and `tableView` can be `nil` in this case. You can find this easily with left side of console.

Answer (score 0):

It's the table's rows that represent the data in `tempArray` so the subscript should be `indexPath.row`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ClaimCell", for: indexPath) as! AllMyClaimsTable
        cell.idField.text = String(tempArray[indexPath.row].id)
        cell.dateField.text = tempArray[indexPath.row].date
        cell.statusField.text = tempArray[indexPath.row].status
        return cell
    }
```

Edit:  Also, add a `didSet` property observer which will reload the table view automatically as your array changes. Although this should just be a temporary workaround to illustrate a point, and to debug your code more easily. Calling `tableView.reloadData()` for every single insertion or deletion is very inefficient.

```
var tempArray: [ClaimProperties] = [] {
    didSet {
        print("didSet...")
        print(tempArray)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

And if you now add a print log inside `cellForRowAt` it should prove that tempArray's values are being set and saved, as you desire.

```
print("In cellForRowAt...")
print(tempArray)
```

**Explanation:**

The reason why your `print(tempArray)` does not print the updated values anywhere else is because tableView's dataSource methods are only called once, when the tableView first appears.  They only get called again when you specifically call the `reloadData` method.  If you add the `didSet` code, it should reload everytime you add to your array, and then `cellForRowAt` will be called *again* at that point in time when your closure has finished executing, which will print the updated (non-empty) `tempArray`.

If the table still does not display after the above fixes, then I think I can say with confidence that the issue lies elsewhere.

Comment: I've changed it to row, and it doesn't have any error when I run it but it doesn't show anything either. I'm guessing it's because my appending tempArray in getTokenFromAPI() didn't get 'saved' outside of the function. Therefore it still remains empty.. but thank you for pointing out on the subscript!

Comment: Aside from this fix, do what @emrcftci suggests in his answer, because the tableView should be reloaded when the data changes.  And that happens in the closure.  Also, your `tempArray` is a property of `DashboardViewController`, so the changes do get saved.  You just need to update your table at the correct time to reflect those changes.

Comment: The reason why I suspect it may not be saved is because I tried printing tempArray everywhere else but do { } and it's empty. However if I print it in do { } of course the data are all there. I'm still new at this, thank you very much for the explanation.

Comment: How about adding a `didSet` modifer for your tempArray, where you call `tableView.reloadData()`.  This way you will see that tempArray's values persist after being set inside the closure, and it might trigger the display update properly.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I've managed to solve the issue and display all data to my table view. I've posted my answer if you're interested. Thank you so much for the explanation, it helped me understand better!